# C# application running as native Android service

Tags: c#, android

I have C# native service that is running on Windows. I would like to port\run it on Android as a native service.

Is it possible to run C# somehow on Android?

What is more appropriate programming language\technology in case of porting (Java/C++)?

Comment: you have to use search before asking. searching for `C# android` would give you what you want.

Comment: For me it is clear, that xamarin could be used, but would it be possible to create native daemon through xamarin and what about SEPolicy in this case?

Comment: Android does not run daemons, it's architecture is different. You can go down to the Linux level, but Androdi's linux capabilities are limited